# Route parameters returning undefined for a specific route param in Remix.run

Tags: react-router, url-parameters, remix.run

My `route` file structure looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqoPi.png).

In my loader of industries.$slug.tsx

```
export async function loader({ params }: LoaderFunctionArgs) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(params))
    return {}
}
```

When I'm at `industries/big-data`
`console.log(JSON.stringify(params))`  shows  `{"slug":"big-data"}`.

But when I'm at `industries/ai`
`console.log(JSON.stringify(params))` shows `{"slug":"undefined"}`. What even is this?

Comment: Hm... looks like there's something wrong with your project. It works fine here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/remix-run-remix-1afd49?file=app%2Froutes%2Findustries.%24slug.tsx

Comment: @kiliman 

`GET /industries/telecommunication?_data=routes%2Findustries.%24slug - - - - ms
GET /industries/telecommunication?_data=routes%2Findustries.%24slug 200 - - 1635.980 ms


GET /industries/artificial-intelligence?_data=routes%2Findustries.%24slug 200 - - 1563.662 ms
GET /industries/undefined 200 - - 2821.253 ms`
see here at the last log the `artificial-intelligence` becomes 'undefined' its strange isn't it?